# Docker container prints "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I am fairly new to docker and I am completely stumped on how to fix my problem. I have searched and searched and nothing I've found has fixed my problem so far.

No matter what I do, I cant seem to get my bash script to be found and executed.

FYI - I'm using dockerfile-maven-plugin to kick-off the docker build process

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

WORKDIR /  ## I've also tried other directories, besides root

ARG JAR_FILE    ## variable inject via dockerfile-maven-plugin
ADD ${JAR_FILE} /motus-exec.jar

ADD run_motus.sh /
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/run_motus.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/run_motus.sh"]
```

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/java -jar /motus-exec.jar
```

Output from building docker image

```
[INFO] Step 1 : FROM openjdk:8-jre
[INFO] Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/openjdk ... 
[INFO] Pulling from docker.io/library/openjdk
[INFO] Digest: sha256:2216ccda45993afaa42b3b269aa1ae8832cb2fabbf8207f63d528fdc7c8a087b
[INFO] Status: Image is up to date for docker.io/openjdk:8-jre
[INFO]  ---> ed287c436e66
[INFO] Step 2 : WORKDIR /
[INFO]  ---> Running in 779de913ad3b
[INFO]  ---> 7ba637ea0ee8
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 779de913ad3b
[INFO] Step 3 : ARG JAR_FILE
[INFO]  ---> Running in 99c86f5273f0
[INFO]  ---> 8b0e9f39c1ab
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 99c86f5273f0
[INFO] Step 4 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} /motus-exec.jar
[INFO]  ---> 4bd2c163c7c3
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 9a9098d6e51a
[INFO] Step 5 : ADD run_motus.sh /
[INFO]  ---> 115cc9b09439
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 51e610f15427
[INFO] Step 6 : RUN chmod +x /run_motus.sh
[INFO]  ---> Running in 62dabd8b432e
[INFO]  ---> 8db646df2936
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 62dabd8b432e
[INFO] Step 7 : ENTRYPOINT /run_motus.sh
[INFO]  ---> Running in 330c5442d61a
[INFO]  ---> 0d9c0f6f5a34
[INFO] Removing intermediate container 330c5442d61a
[INFO] Successfully built 0d9c0f6f5a34
```

Output when I run image

```
>> docker run tl/motus-sol:0.2.2-SNAPSHOT
no such file or directory
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You aren't per chance on a Windows host?

Comment: Hi David - No I'm building and running on the same Centos7 host.

Comment: I would say the issue is that you don't have a CMD either in your Dockefile, either in your `docker run` command.

Comment: Could you try something like `docker run tl/motus-sol:0.2.2-SNAPSHOT ls`?

Comment: Hi - I tried running `docker run tl/motus-sol:0.2.2-SNAPSHOT ls` and got the same results. I will try adding a CMD and see what I get.

Comment: Most likely you have a special character around #!/bin/sh. I used to have this issue if I edit the .sh file in Windows then having a special character \r at the end of the line

Comment: anhlc - You are my savior. That was exactly my problem. I build on Centos, but I have a habit of making updates on my Windows laptop. Updating the file format in Notepad++ to Unix (LF) fixed my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonSnouffer, good to know that helps. I tried to make an answer here to help other with same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker run with 'Container command not found or does not exist' means the command in the entrypoint does not exist.

In your case the command in the .sh file: sh or java both exist in the image openjdk:8-jre. So you can check the issue in the shell script syntax.
If you edit the sh file with a Windows editor, make sure you don't have the CRLF (\r\n) at the end of the command. One way to remove \r is to run `sed` before add the sh file to the container:

```
sed -e 's/\r//g' run_motus.sh
```